# Azure DevOps: “rzc generate exited with code 2”

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-3.1, razorgenerator, c#-9.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.x project that is built and deployed using Azure DevOps Pipelines. After upgrading the project to use C# 9.0—but *not* ASP.NET Core 5.0—my `dotnet build` (`DotNetCoreCLI@2`) task warns:

> Unknown C# language version 9.0.

#### Error

Immediately after the warning, the task fails with the following error:

> ##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets(150,5): **Error : rzc generate exited with code 2.**

#### Task

There's nothing particularly special about my build task, but for completeness:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: '*.sln'
    arguments: '/p:configuration=$(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore'
```

#### Conditions

It's worth noting that:

- The project builds fine using `dotnet build` on my local machine.
- If I remove the ASP.NET Core 3.x project, leaving only my .NET Core 3.x class libraries, everything builds fine.
- If I replace the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task with a `VSBuild@1` task, everything also builds fine.

Given that, this issue only occurs when the project meets *all* of the following conditions:

- The project uses the either the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` or the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK.
- The project uses a `TargetFramework` of either `netcoreapp3.0` or `netcoreapp3.1`.
- The project uses a `LangVersion` of `9.0`.
- The project is built using the Azure DevOps `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue isn't specific to Azure DevOps Pipelines. Instead, the issue appears to be due to an incompatibility between the Razor compiler built into the .NET 3.x SDK and C# 9.0. This *necessitates* the availability of the .NET 5.x SDK in order to compile a project with Razor views and C# 9.0—even if that project itself is a .NET 3.x project.

#### Azure DevOps Pipelines

As this question is specifically about Azure DevOps Pipelines, this can be resolved by explicitly adding the *Use .NET Core SDK* task to your pipeline and configuring it use the .NET 5.x SDK:

```yaml
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 5.x'
  inputs:
    version: 5.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

#### Notes

- Even though .NET 5 is released, you still must set `includePreviewVersions` currently.
- The .NET 5 SDK can still build the project, despite it being an ASP.NET Core 3.x project.
- Other tasks in your pipeline (such as `gitversion`, in my case) may explicitly depend on the .NET Core 3.x SDK; if so, you'll need to install that as well:

  ```yaml
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 3.x'
    inputs:
      version: 3.x
  ```

This step is probably obvious if you've upgraded your project to use .NET 5.0 and ASP.NET Core 5.0, but may not be obvious if you're still using .NET 3.x and have only upgraded to C# 9.0—and, in fact, it still isn’t necessary if your .NET project doesn’t need to compile Razor.

Comment: Please tell me where you are entering the text examples you show. I'm having the same error, but it points to the .csproj file where I can't see/figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @EoRaptor013: This text is within the YAML for my Azure Pipeline. The error may still point to your `csproj`, as it’s going to encounter the issue on build. But the root problem is that .NET 5 must be installed to compile an ASP.NET Core 3.x project—or a Razor Class Library with views—using C# 9.0. If you’re not using Azure Pipelines, just make sure that .NET 5 is installed on the machine doing the build.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have a yaml pipeline as this is a straight-up local web project. I did, however, find a reference to Razor in the csproj file. Not using Razor here, so don't know why the line was there. Deleted the line and all is well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue/error as you, except when doing a `docker build`. Everything built fine locally, but `docker build` failed with those same two errors you mention. Based you [your answer about .NET 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65014098/3025856), I changed the docker base image from:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS backend
```

And the `docker build` works fine now.

> ***Note:*** I'm still using .NET Core 3.1 in the code base; all I did was upgrade the build image.

Comment: Oh, that’s interesting. That makes perfect sense. I suppose on a developer workstation, it’s more likely that both .NET Core 3 and .NET 5 might be installed for someone working on such a project, but not necessarily on a virtual machine—be that via a Docker manifest or a CI/CD pipeline instance.